# Unexpected may be uninitialized warning on optional

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization

For some reasons on gcc 9 (was not on lower version) `lto-wrapper` running `c++` returns

```
[  9%] Linking CXX executable tests
/home/yuki/prj/processing/processor/parser_schedule.cpp: In member function ‘scheduleWithConfig’:
/home/yuki/prj/processing/processor/parser_schedule.cpp:212:30: error: ‘MEM[(struct duration *)&downloadInterval + 8B]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  212 |     boost::optional<seconds> downloadInterval;
      |                              ^
lto1: all warnings being treated as errors
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/bin/c++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/processor.dir/build.make:395: processor] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:889: CMakeFiles/processor.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/yuki/prj/processing/processor/parser_schedule.cpp: In member function ‘scheduleWithConfig’:
/home/yuki/prj/processing/processor/parser_schedule.cpp:212:30: error: ‘MEM[(struct duration *)&downloadInterval + 8B]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  212 |     boost::optional<seconds> downloadInterval;
      |                              ^
lto1: all warnings being treated as errors
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/bin/c++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tests.dir/build.make:395: tests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:862: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all] Error 2
```

on roughly this snippet of code

```
    // For some reasons GCC 9 says "may be used uninitialized in this function".
    boost::optional<seconds> downloadInterval;

    if (something) {
        downloadInterval = seconds(1800);
    }
```

I tried `=boost::none`, `{}`, diagnostic ingore on this line `-Wuninitialized"` or `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized` - none worked. Only global `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized` sealed the deal. I am not particularly happy to run the whole project with the warning disabled. Any idea how to solve this particular issue.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: The problem most likely is not the shown code, but some code beneath it that is using `downloadInterval`.

Comment: You seem to initialize `downloadInterval` conditionally. When you use `downloadInterval` are you doing that conditionally as well? Do you check that it has been initialized?

Comment: "I tried `=boost::none`, `{}`" - these both resolve to an initialized optional _with no value_. Meaning that if you later try to read the optional, it will be reading unitialized (data member) value in the case where the optional is still empty. The detailed error message `error: ‘MEM[(struct duration *)&downloadInterval + 8B]’` diagnoses an attempted access within the `downloadInterval` object, hinting that you may attempting to read the "maybe stored" value of the optional whilst it is actually "none". Make sure the optional has a value when you access it (e.g. `get_optional_value_or`).

Comment: Look at gcc's bugzilla, there are many reports of optional-related false positives of this warning.

Comment: I am sure, I do check if optional is initialized before reading it.